# How are the compressed models stored in the EF 4.3 Code First Migrations __MigrationHistory table created?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working with Code First Migrations (Entity Framework 4.3) and I'd like to get a compressed binary version of the current model, so that I can manually compare it to the latest model stored in the `__MigrationHistory` table (or to one I have stored in a text file).

<strike>There is the `EdmMetadata.TryGetModelHash()` method, but that's marked as deprecated and I want to avoid it if possible (for future-proofing reasons).</strike>

How would I do this under EF 4.3?

**Edit:** From a bit more investigation and the info in [Pawel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10694348/43140) I've figured out that this field no longer stores a hash but a compressed binary representation of the model. It's this I'm trying to create.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`__MigrationHistory` table no longer contains a hash of the model. Instead it now contains the model in the compressed form. Also, verifying whether the model changed or not no longer relies on just comparing the hash since Migrations need to "know" what changed and how it did change.

`EdmMetadata` was a table that was being used before Migrations were integrated to Entity Framowork in 4.3/5.0 and won't be created in databases created by EF 4.3+. You can find some additional details here as well: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/01/13/ef-4-3-beta-1-what-happened-to-that-edmmetadata-table/

Comment: Thanks, just after I posted this I realised that the `Model` field was actually storing binary data rather than a hash, so this confirms my suspicion. However it still doesn't really answer the question of how I would *create* a compatible compressed version of my model—though +1 for some useful info.

Comment: Uncompressing the model using zip/gzip should give you the edmx file.

Comment: So how would I create that—as far as I know there are no `edmx` files involved when using the Code First approach?

Comment: In fact edmx is involved when using the Code First only you don't see it. You would use EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.edmxwriter(v=vs.103).aspx